# Joomla can't write to the configuration file

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, joomla3.0

I've just installed Joomla on XAMPP - I'm an absolute beginner.
When I try to change something in Global Configuration i get the following message:
An error has occured.
0 Could not write to the configuration file.

I had to create the configuration.php myself, because it wasn't done automatically - could this be the cause?

I've downloaded the latest version of Joomla! - 3.4.3, PHP is version 5.6.3

All i could find regarding this problem was just too advanced for me to understand. 
Hopefully someone can help me? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's definitely a permissions issue: your web server (XAMPP) cannot write the configuration into the configuration.php file. You should make sure it's writeable by the web server user.
Depending on the operating system you're on, the procedure to apply the correct settings may change. I am pretty sure you can find someone else who solved the same issue at [XAMPP forums](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/index.php).

## EDIT: a note about permissions

Generally speaking, giving full write access to your configuration.php file is *not* a good idea.

For this specific situation, since you're dealing with XAMPP, I assume is a local webserver that no one else will have access to, so it's ok as a workaround.

Just keep in mind that if you're going to have the same problem on your production server, rw-rw-rw- will *not* be a correct solution and more proper permissions settings will be necessary.

Comment: thanks so much!! the file was r/w r r, i now changed it to r/w r/w r/w and it works!!

Comment: Happy to hear that! But please read my edit about permissions.

Answer (score 1):

They are both symptoms of the same issue, which is either permissions or file ownership.  Since you are local what you should do is make sure that the file is writable and also check the ownership an make sure it is the same as all the other files.

In the meantime the solution in Joomla is that you can enable the FTP layer. You do this by editing the configuration.php file. At this point just try to edit it directly from the file system, but by doing that you may also be able to figure out who owns it.